# how to scrape some tags using Beautifulsoup on python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL I am trying to Scrape: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wsandroid.suite

[image]

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pkg = "com.wsandroid.suite"
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + pkg
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
appTitle = soup.find("div", {"class": "document-title"}).text
date = soup.find("div", {"itemprop", "datePublished"})
print appTitle
print date  #THIS PRINTS NOTHING
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
mine-MBP:learningpython neilnidhi$ python playstorescraper.py
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wsandroid.suite
 Security & Power Booster -free 
None //**NOTHING IS GETTING PRINTED HERE**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of typos which are causing your problems.  Compare the format of your `appTitle` variable and your `date` variable.

Change

```
date = soup.find("div", {"itemprop", "datePublished"})
```

to

```
date = soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "datePublished"}).text
```